# How to get intersection points between "each line" and "multiple circles intersected with that line"?

Tags: computational-geometry, intersection, procedural-programming

The following code is used to draw circles;

```
 pts={{0.02,0.44},{0.08,0.58},{0.22,0.57},{0.3,0.9},{0.39,0.24},{0.44,0.79},{0.65,0.19},{0.82,0.93},{0.93,0.7},{0.95,0.11}}
 r = 0.2; 
 Show[Graphics[{Blue, Circle[#, r] & /@ pts, Black, Point[pts], 
      FaceForm[Opacity[.5,LightBlue]],EdgeForm[{Thick,Darker@Blue}],disks}]]
```

The output would be as the following image;

[image: Multiple circles image]

I want to do the following;

- **Label** the *circles' centers* *according to the order* of the **pts** points; e.g. circle with *center pts of {0.02,0.044}* has the label of **X1** and so on for other circles.
- Draw **multiple lines** that have **start point (0,0)** with **different angles (0:5:90).**
- For each line;

  - Get the **number** of circles, *intersected with* that line.
  - Get the **indices** of circles that *intersected with* that line.
  - Get **intersection points' values** that resulted from the intersection 
     between that line and the circles which intersected with that line.
  - **Sort** these intersection points **ascending x-coordintes**.

So, the output would be like the following image; **But adding also tool-tip**; So, **by clicking on each line; I should get the output like that;**

**For example;** *By clicking on the line of degree(0);*
it should give the following output;

> - Line of **degree**: 0
> - **no. of circles** intersected with that line: 2
> - **Indices of circles** intersected with that line: X7 , X8
> - **Points of intersection values** ,sorted ascending to x-axis:
>
>   - Points with *line and circle X7* *`C1(x1,y1),C1(x2,y2)`*: {{0.5878,0},{0.71222,0}}
>   - Points with *line and circle X8* *`C2(x1,y1),C2(x2,y2)`*: {{0.78307,0},{1.117,0}}

[image: Intersectio points]

- Then make loop as following to get value of L;

[image: Loop to get value of L]

Where;

- m: is the number of circles intersected with each line.
- C: is the intersection points.
- j: is the index of each circle j=1,.....,m.

Any suggestions for code to do that??

Answer (score 2):

This gets you part of the way

```
pts = {{0.02, 0.44}, {0.08, 0.58}, {0.22, 0.57}, {0.3, 0.9}, {0.39, 0.24},
 {0.44, 0.79}, {0.65, 0.19}, {0.82, 0.93}, {0.93, 0.7}, {0.95, 0.11}};
labels = {"x1", "x2", "x3", "x4", "x5", "x6", "x7", "x8", "x9", "x10"};
angles = Table[{Cos[a], Sin[a]}, {a, 0, 90 Degree, 5 Degree}];
endpts = Map[#*1.2/(Max @@ #) &, angles];
r = 0.2;
int = Quiet[Table[Map[{x, y} /. 
   Solve[{y == Tan[a] x, (y - #[[2]])^2 + (x - #[[1]])^2 == r^2}, {x, y},
     Reals]&, pts], {a, 0, 85 Degree, 5 Degree}]];
Print["Get the number of circles, intersected with that line=", 
  Map[Length, int /. {x, y} -> Sequence[]]];
Print["Get the indices of circles that intersected with that line=", 
  Map[First, Map[Thread[{Range[10], #}]&, int] /. {_, {x, y}}->Sequence[], {2}]];
Print["Intersection points' values that resulted from the intersection between that \
  line and the circles which intersected with that line=", 
  Map[Partition[Flatten[#], 2]&, int /. {x, y}->Sequence[]]];
Print["Sort these intersection points ascending x-coordintes=", 
  Map[SortBy[#, First]&, Map[Partition[Flatten[#], 2]&, int /. {x, y}->Sequence[]]]];
Show[Graphics[{Blue, Circle[#, r]& /@ pts, Black, Point[pts], 
  FaceForm[Opacity[.5, LightBlue]], EdgeForm[{Thick, Darker@Blue}]}],
  Graphics[{Text @@@ Thread[{labels, pts}]}], 
  Graphics[{Line[{{0, 0}, #}]& /@ endpts}], 
  Graphics[{Red, Circle[#, .02]& /@ Partition[Flatten[int /. {x, y}->Sequence[]], 2]}]]
```

You should be able to take each one of those `Print` and turn them into your interactive graphical tool tip clicking manipulate application.

You should be very careful with this and test it extensively. It appears to work with the example data you had, but I would not be surprised if there are problems if you had, for example, a line which intersected no circles or other similar unusual cases.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help and your notice.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't do compute l parts but here's the function to compute values:

```
compulteInterSection[l : Line[{x1_, y2_}], circles_] :=    
 Module[{degree, res, n, ind, points},
  degree = ArcTan @@ (y2 - x1);
  res = RegionIntersection[l, #] & /@ circles;
  n = Count[res, _Point];
  ind = Flatten[Position[res, _Point]];
  points = 
   Sort[If[VectorQ[#], {#}, #]] & /@ Cases[res, _Point][[All, 1]];
  {degree, n, ind, points}
  ]
```

Some utility function to make pod:

```
makePod[{deg_, 0, _, _}] := Grid[{
   {"Line of Degree:", deg},
   {"# of circle intersect:", 0},
   {"Indices of circles", "" },
   {"Points of intersection values: ", ""}
   }, Alignment -> {Left, Top}
  ]

makePod[{deg_, n_, ind_, points_}] :=
 Grid[{
   {"Line of Degree:", deg},
   {"# of circle intersect:", n},
   {"Indices of circles", 
    StringTrim[StringJoin["X" <> ToString[#] <> ", " & /@ ind], 
     ", "] },
   {"Points of intersection values: ", Grid[points]}
   }, Alignment -> {Left, Top}
  ]
```

I just make the example using Manipulate, you could modify it other form you want. It has a tooltip:

```
labels = Text[Style["X" <> ToString[#1], Red, 14], #2, {0, -1} ] & @@@
    Transpose[{Range[Length[circles]], pts}];

circles = Circle[#, r] & /@ pts;

Manipulate[
 Block[{res},
  res = compulteInterSection[Line[{{0, 0}, 2 {Cos[p], Sin[p]}}], 
    circles];
  Overlay[{Graphics[{Blue, circles, 
      labels, {ColorData["Rainbow"][2 p /Pi], 
       Tooltip[Line[{{0, 0}, 2 {Cos[p], Sin[p]}}], makePod[res]], Red,
        Circle[#, .015] & /@ Flatten[res[[4]], 1]}}, Frame -> True, 
     PlotRange -> {{-0.2, 1.2}, {-0.2, 1.2}}, ImagePadding -> 40], 
    If[pq, Panel[Chop@makePod[res]], Nothing]}, All, 1]
  ],
 {p, 0, Pi/2},
 {{pq, False, "show pod"}, {True, False}}, ContentSize -> {420, 400}
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.